# How to select a portion of dataframe as new dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Sample Dataframe]

here is the image of the original dataframe in pandas. But i want to slice the dataframe based on the location of "START" value in the dataframe.

I would want to search the entire data frame for 'START' and then select all values after START as the column ex. MONTH1, MONTH2, MONTH3 ....until data extends( i want to select range from location of "START" +1 till end) as columns of the new data frame and 630,559,994,501 ....... would be rows till the end of the new data frame.

output final dataframe to be as below

[image: final data frame]

Comment: this your question is really not clear. could you create a sample dataframe and then show what you expect the output to be?

Comment: dataframe image is posted

Answer (score 1):

use .index to find row number of "START" string, later use .iloc to slice dataframe:

```
idx = df.index.get_loc(df[df['Column_Name'] == 'START'].index[0]) # case sensitive
sub_df= df.iloc[idx:,1:]
```

Update, as per your comment:
if column name is not known, but you know it's location (number), use .iloc to select column by it's number

```
idx = df.index.get_loc(df[df.iloc[:,0] == 'START'].index[0]) # case sensitive
```

Comment: i tried it but i still need to fix my column names, currently column names dont change and remain same as original data frame are 217,81,, 430......639 and below that is MONTH1, MONTH2....  how do i shift down and make MONTH1, MONTH2 as the columns instead